# Sharepoint/InfoPath 2010 Insert into a external database and sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have a Infopath form that add items to a database via a web service. (This part works fine).
I was wondering if it is possible to upload this form to sharepoint site (I know you can do this part), but also to be able to submit to the sharepoint library?

If so how would I go about submitting to a sharepoint library? Would I have to do it via my web service?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint you have a so called forms library. This library can have a form template, i.e. InfoPath template. This template could very well be your form which submits to this form library as well to some external database via a webservice.